# (Greek) Stylized Alpha

Tags: greek, inscription, typography

[image: 1.]
[image: 2.]
[image: 3.]

Are those triangular tripods merely highly stylised Alpha's? Or are they Alpha-Upsilon digraphs?

*(Sorry, the websites didn't give the explanation of where the photos were taken.)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just the way they write alpha. In the first one, for example:
αναπαυσον την ψυχην αυτου μετα των αγιων ....

Comment: Surely ψυχην rather than τυχην ?

Comment: Thanks alot, :) Because that alpha in the bottom right of the first photo is just waaaayyy wacky..

Comment: How do you explain, in the third picture, what looks like "ao" for the omega in "σωφροσύνη"? And also what looks like aretaōn? (I don't have time to look through it carefully, so I might be splitting the words wrong)

Comment: @brianpck: Looks like contracted vowels are being resolved - historically the forms *were* σαοφροσύνη and ἀρετάων, before contraction.

Comment: @varro. Yes L/S have: " Ep. and poet. σᾰοφροσύνη (as in Hom. and in later poetry, IG22.3632.11, 3753)".

Comment: @varro. And yes, it must be ψυχην, as now emended.